# PLSQL - get the line where exception occured

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql

Is it possible to catch the line where an exception occurred?

Given the following PL/SQL block:

```
l_path1_value := l_xmltype.extract('/SOME_PATH1').getStringVal();
l_path2_value := l_xmltype.extract('/SOME_PATH2').getStringVal();
l_path3_value := l_xmltype.extract('/SOME_PATH3').getStringVal();
```

When the `extract` function will return `null` then `SELF_IS_NULL` exception will be thrown. Is it possible get the error line when the error was thrown?

```
WHEN SELF_IS_NULL THEN
    --get error line and save it somewhere
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try creating a wrapper function to the `extract` function and do define a `EXCEPTION SELF_IS_NULL` and use `RAISE SELF_IS_NULL;` if it returns NULL.

`dbms_output.put_line( SQLERRM||chr(10)||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace );`

Please put this in your exception block. It prints the stack trace from where it originated(Line NO)

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to use a checkpoint variable, similar to the following:

```
BEGIN
  strXMLelement := '/SHOW_SHIPMENT_005/DATAAREA/SHOW_SHIPMENT/SHIPMENT/SHIPITEM/QUANTITY/VALUE/text()';
  l_XMLvalue := l_xmltype.extract(strXMLelement ).getStringVal();
  dbms_output.put_line('QUANTITY: '||l_XMLvalue);

  strXMLelement := '/SHOW_SHIPMENT_005/DATAAREA/SHOW_SHIPMENT/SHIPMENT/SHIPITEM/DOCUMNTREF/DOCUMENTID/text()';
  l_XMLdocument_id := l_xmltype.extract(strXMLelement ).getStringVal();
  dbms_output.put_line('DOCUMENT ID:' ||l_XMLdocument_id);

  strXMLelement := '/SHOW_SHIPMENT_005/DATAAREA/SHOW_SHIPMENT/SHIPMENT/SHIPITEM/DOCUMNTREF/USERAREA/DOCUMENTRELEASE/text()';
  l_XMLdoc_release := l_xmltype.extract(strXMLelement).getStringVal();
  dbms_output.put_line('DOCUMENT RELEASE:' ||l_XMLdoc_release);

  strXMLelement := '/SHOW_SHIPMENT_005/DATAAREA/SHOW_SHIPMENT/SHIPMENT/SHIPITEM/DOCUMNTREF/LINENUM/text()';
  l_XMLlinenum := l_xmltype.extract(strXMLelement).getStringVal();
  dbms_output.put_line('LINE NUMBER:' ||l_XMLlinenum);

  strXMLelement := '/SHOW_SHIPMENT_005/DATAAREA/SHOW_SHIPMENT/SHIPMENT/SHIPITEM/DOCUMNTREF/SCHLINENUM/text()';
  l_XMLsch_lnum := l_xmltype.extract(strXMLelement).getStringVal();
  dbms_output.put_line('SCHIPMENT LINE NUMBER:' ||l_XMLsch_lnum);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN SELF_IS_NULL THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error extracting ' || strXMLelement || ' : ' ||
                         'SQLCODE=' || SQLCODE || '  SQLERRM=' || SQLERRM);
END;
```

Share and enjoy.